# Cannot open log file Xorg.pid

Tags: login, xorg, gdm, ldap

I encounter serious problem. When I am trying to login to my LDAP User, gdm doesn't start my user session and want me to log in again.

- I have connection to LDAP Server
- I can login to that account on terminal eg `Ctrl+Alt+F2`
- Other accounts can log in
- Login is 100% correct

I checked output of `journalctl -f` and I found this:

```
lip 13 11:53:08 apple23 systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1011.
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: (EE)
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: Fatal server error:
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: (EE) Cannot open log file "/home/others/ldapuser/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-1776.log"
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: (EE)
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]:          at http://wiki.x.org
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]:  for help.
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: (EE)
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1774]: Unable to run X server
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 gdm-password][1752]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user ldapuser
lip 13 11:53:09 apple23 gdm3[1158]: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0,041535 seconds
```

On the server I doesn't have this file `/home/others/ldapuser/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-1776.log` and when I creating it by myself with touch, then there will be another file with different number of PID.

Any clues how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason of the problem. My `home.mount` service had been failing. So I run `systemctl start home.mount` and after that my ldap account has `.Xauthority` file which will give me permissions to run X server.

If you have a similar problem run `systemctl` and check if something is unusual.

Comment: Hi @eddy
I am facing an identical issue (not on ubuntu though) with the same error message about a xorg log file and apparent .Xauthority issue but it's not caused by home.mount. How did you figure out which service was failing ?